# How to access one class from another using association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I access one class from another using association. Say I have following code. How can I get account and account history from supplier class and also form account class how can I get other two class value.

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
  has_one :account_history, through: :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_one :account_history
end

class AccountHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? Are you trying to access the associations on an instance of the class or on the class itself?

```
# How can I get account from supplier class
Supplier.last.account

# How can I get account history from supplier class
Supplier.last.account.account_history

# how can I get other two class value
Account.last.supplier
Account.last.account_history
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to access Account with supplier

```
Supplier.find("id of that").accout
```

if you want to access AccountHistory than

```
Supplier.find("id of that").accout_history
```

Comment: Can I really access account_history directly from supplier or do I have to access it via account like Supplier.find("id of that").account.account_history

Comment: you can access it directly . otherwise there is no meaning of defining  has_one :account_history, through: :account. when you directly access it will automatically find account_history through account